# if I use multiplicative suffixes in systemd it errors - "failed to parse resource value"

Tags: debian, systemd, services

Odd issue, this'n!

As per [the systemd man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)..

`"The multiplicative suffixes K (=1024), M (=1024*1024) and so on for G, T, P and E may be used for resource limits measured in bytes (e.g. LimitAS=16G)."`

Accordingly, I used a .service file that looks like this..

```
[Unit]
Description=FreeSWITCH
After=syslog.target network.target local-fs.target

[Service]
; service
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/freeswitch/freeswitch.pid
Environment="DAEMON_OPTS=-nonat"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/freeswitch
ExecStart=/usr/bin/freeswitch -u freeswitch -g freeswitch -ncwait $DAEMON_OPTS
TimeoutSec=45s
Restart=always
; exec
User=root
Group=daemon
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitNOFILE=100000
LimitNPROC=60000
LimitSTACK=240K
LimitRTPRIO=infinity
LimitRTTIME=7000000
IOSchedulingClass=realtime
IOSchedulingPriority=2
CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
CPUSchedulingPriority=89
UMask=0007

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now when I run `systemctl daemon-reload` the syslog prints out.. `systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/freeswitch.service:22] Failed to parse resource value, ignoring: 240K`

If I run `systemctl start freeswitch` it activates the service, and simply uses the default system value (as per `ulimit -s`)

I've tried to setting the logging for systemd to debug. Nothing else gets printed out.

Any idea on what might be the issue? I'm using Debian Jessie.

Comment: Does the online `man` page you quote refer to the same `systemd` version as you have installed?  `systemd` used to change quite regularly and it may be that your implementation doesn't support these multiplicative suffixes? I mention it, because I've been caught out by that one :-)

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.. I naively assumed the 'apt-get install systemd' would install the latest absolute version, but it didn't! Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility to use suffixes like `K` and `M were introduced with [systemd 228](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v228/NEWS#L54), Debian Jessie ships [systemd 215](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/systemd) and hence cannot use this feature. As a workaround you can manually perform the multiplication and specify bytes instead.